# "sharing" parts of a reactive stream over multiple rest calls

Tags: java, rx-java2, spring-webflux, akka-stream, project-reactor

I have this **Spring WebFlux** controller:

```
@RestController
public class Controller
{
    @PostMapping("/doStuff")
    public Mono<Response> doStuff(@RequestBody Mono<Request> request)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Now, say I wanted to **relate separate requests** coming to this controller from different clients to group processing based on some property of the `Request` object.

**Take 1:**

```
@PostMapping("/doStuff")
public Mono<Response> doStuff(@RequestBody Mono<Request> request)
{
    return request.flux()
                  .groupBy(r -> r.someProperty())
                  .flatMap(gf -> gf.map(r -> doStuff(r)));
}
```

This will not work, because every call will get its own instance of the stream. The whole `flux()` call doesn't make sense, there will always ever be one `Request` object going through the stream even if there's many of those streams fired at the same time as a result of simultaneous calls coming from clients. What I need, I gather, is some part of the stream that is shared between all requests where I could do my grouping, which led me to this slightly over engineered code

**Take 2:**

```
private AtomicReference<FluxSink<Request>> sink = new AtomicReference<>();
private Flux<Response> serializingStream;


public Controller()
{
    this.serializingStream =
        Flux.<Request>create(fluxSink -> sink.set(fluxSink), ERROR)
            .groupBy(r -> r.someProperty())
            .flatMap(gf -> gf.map(r -> doStuff(r)));
            .publish()
            .autoConnect();

    this.serializingStream.subscribe().dispose(); //dummy subscription to set the sink;
}

@PostMapping("/doStuff")
public Mono<Response> doStuff(@RequestBody Request request)
{
    req.setReqId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    return
        serializingStream
            .doOnSubscribe(__ -> sink.get().next(req))
            .filter(resp -> resp.getReqId().equals(req.getReqId()))
            .take(1)
            .single();
}
```

And this kind of works, though it looks like I am doing things I shouldn't (or at least they don't feel right), like leaking the `FluxSink` and then injecting a value through it while subscribing, adding a request ID so that I can then filter the right response. Also, if error happens in the `serializingStream` then it breakes everything for everyone, but I guess I could try to isolate the errors to keep things going.

**The question is, is there a better way of doing this that doesn't feel like an open heart surgery.**

Also, related question for a similar scenario. I was thinking about using `Akka Persistence` to implement event sourcing and have it trigerred from inside that `Reactor` stream. I was reading about `Akka Streams` that allow to wrap an Actor and then there's some ways of converting that into something that can be hooked up with `Reactor` (aka `Publisher` or `Subscriber`), but then if every requests gets it's own stream, I am effectively loosing back pressure and am risking OOME because of flooding the Persistent Actor's mailbox, so I guess that problem falls in to the same category like the one I described above.

Comment: I've been reading akka-streams documentation. It looks this sort of requirement could be achieved by using `Source.queue`. A request would put a `Tuple` of `Request` and `CompletableFuture<Response>` onto the stream and return the `CompletableFuture`  back. The stream logic would then, when done with the Request, complete the `CompletableFuture` and therefore trigerring sending it back to the original rest call requestor. This would effectively pump all the requests through a "shared" stream...